# Understanding child theme functions.php

Tags: php, css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have successfully created a child theme for the `Emmet Lite template`, using the information provided on [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and [here](http://www.getmotopress.com/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme-3/)

The CSS file of the child theme looks like this:

```
/*
Theme name: Emmet Child
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/
Description: This is a child of Emmet Lite theme
Author: Motopress
Author URI: http://www.getmotopress.com/
Template: emmet-lite
Version: 1.0
*/

/* Adjustments to the Emmet Lite template start here */

.top-header {
display: none;  
}

.site-header {
background-color: #FFC421;
}
```

I firstly added the `@import` function, but that didn't work for me. What I read is that the parent css was loaded after the child, so the last one wins.
To counter this I added a `functions.php` to my child folder and removed the `@import`. This looks like this:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'     );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

So all is working correctly, the changes/overrides I made inside the `style.css` of the child folder are correctly applied on my website.

**Understanding the situation:**

My question is:

The parent `Emmet` theme uses CSS files called differently than `style.css`. The names used by this template are ...

- emmet-style.min.css
- emmet-style.css

(They are located in the theme folder, path: emmet-lite/css/emmet-style.css)

It includes also a set of other styles for Woocommerce, Buddypress, Bootstrap, but the only file I use for editing is emmet-style.min.css.

I would like to understand what I'm doing here, even if it already works. I'm not into PHP, so from my understanding this line of code calls a wrong CSS but still works?

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

The style.css should be `emmet-style.min.css` or is it always `style.css` no matter what? I don't see anything mentioned in the documentation when developing a `functions.php` which mentions to change the `style.css` path to the correct CSS path. So I probably misunderstand the PHP here.

Can somebody help me explain more in-depth what is going on inside the `functions.php` for child themes and the paths given ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I read is that the parent css was loaded after the child, so the
>   last one wins

It depends on the order in which theme developer is loading stylesheets.

Normally WordPress loads child theme's `functions.php` first and then parent theme's `functions.php`.

> the parent Emmet theme uses CSS files called differently than
>   Style.css

Yes it does. The `style.css` in the root folder of the theme is **only needed** for WordPress to properly identify the theme from it's header.

`style.css` **doesn't need to be enqueued** if doesn't have any CSS properties other than theme header.

We can use any other name for the stylesheets and load them differently but `style.css` with theme header need to be there in the root folder to be identified as a theme by WordPress.

Normally some theme developers like to organize all the stylesheets in css folder, this is also the case used by the Emmet Lite theme developer.

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'     );
```

you don't need to enqueue the above parent `style.css` since it doesn't have any CSS rules.It's just a overhead.

**Then how it's working now ?**

If we take a look at parent theme's [`functions.php`](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/emmet-lite/1.4.3/inc/theme/init.php) , we can see that it loads stylesheets in the following order.

- Bootstrap
- Font Awesome
- Flex Slider
- Main Style ( `/css/emmet-style.min.css` )
- **...**
- **...**
- Finally stylesheet uri ( which basically means active theme's `style.css`)

So here the parent theme is loading the required `/css/emmet-style.min.css` file first and then loadin the `style.css` , this is the style.css of the active theme, in your case child theme's `style.css`.So you don't even need to use the following code as it is already done by the parent theme.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
```

**Paths**

- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) gives the current active theme folder uri.
- [`get_template_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) gives the parent theme folder uri if it doesn't have one then the current theme folder.